# InvalidApp error while red5's client side code with flex

Tags: apache-flex, red5

I am trying to make simple chat program using red5 server using flex builder 3.
I am using eclispe galilio 3.5 for server side code.i have installed jdk 1.6 update 14 and apache ant 1.7.1.when i am running demo program already in red5 then its fine!. but my own code is giving

NetConnection.Connect.InvalidApp
NetConnection.Connect.Closed
or
NetConnection.Connect.Failed

error.when i try (test is red5 demo code )

nc.connect( "rtmp://localhost/test" ,true); 
code then its working.but when i put my folder(firstapp) name  in place of test then giving same error.
please help me what should i do?

Answer (score 0):

in order to make this work you will have 2 parts
1. flexbuilder application which connects to your red5 server
2. java application which you build in eclipse, then copy to the red5 webapp folder

never forget to Restart the red5 - at start it compiles/runs the apps in the webapp folder

post your script from eclipse to register client and the script from flexbuilder to connect to red5

Kind regards

Wim